# Click-To-Dial in Microsoft Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, integration, tapi

I am working in Microsoft Access 2007 and would like to implement click-to-dial capabilities from within the MS Access program for all the computers in the office. I have never done any work with TAPI prior to this and am not sure where to start. How can I go about setting this up if the TAPI drivers are already installed?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

J.D.

Comment: [Let me Google that for you](http://bit.ly/ZLGg3I)...  In all seriousness, this a very vague question.  Could you do some research and form a more specific inquiry? (I was not the one to downvote your question).

Answer (score 0):

First, you should start at the [TAPI.info](http://www.tapi.info/default.aspx/TAPI/PSDKSamples.html) site and [Julmar.com](http://www.julmar.com/tapi/).
There are [SDK and examples](http://www.tapi.info/) or usage from VB6 and VBScript that should be easily translated into MSAccess VBA.

If I were you, I would start with trying to first get good understanding of the TAPI, read documentation, learn about the capabilities and the philosophy behind it.
Then there are [tools](http://www.i-b-a-m.de/Andreas_Marschall%27s_Toto_Tools.htm#_Toc152927322) to help you explore the TAPI and play with it.

Once you are comfortable using the TAPI, you can start programming against it.